# Android - get APK certificate of last release

Tags: android, google-play

I've got a project to do- I got an app and I have some changes to do on that.
The app already been uploaded as a beta version to the Google play developer console,
Now I try to upload a new apk with some changes I made so I sign the APK with my own certificate, well it's says the APK must be signed with the last certificate,
Therefore- I want to know if there is somehow to get the last certificate and sign it by myself or should I ask from the last programmer the certificate that he has been used?

Answer (score 1):

> i want to know if there is somehow to get the last certificate and sign it by myself or should i ask from the last programmer the certificate that he has been used?

You answered yourself pretty much here. If you do not have `last certificate` then you need to ask for it the one who has it, or you must change `packageId` (thus making it a new app) and then release as new app in to Google Play.

This is related read in official docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please [accept it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)